# button clicked and smart slider will sliderto relevant item accordingly

Tags: css, wordpress

i having a issues  with wordpress website to control the button and smart slider . When the buttin cliked , the slider will slide to the item accordingly.

[image]

[image]
website link:
https://metatreasure.io/

Answer (score 0):

Your button has not been linked to your product so it is not working

Comment: Hi sir , what mean by not linked ? i would like to link adn control the slider. can you guide?

Comment: I can see you are using elementor. Using it simply select the button then open the button setting and place the link in the image you want to show on the button. that's it.

Comment: Sir , there are 2 different component .button clicked and trigger  slider to move to select iten .and slider are using smart slider . there were no direct url link to the image. can you pls elaborate how your method work?